# Problem converting java.util.Date to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, jodatime, java.util.date

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
```

With this date or with the following ones it's all OK:

- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(0,0,1,2,30))` — 1900-01-01T02:30:00.000
- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(111,4,24,19,51))` — 2011-05-24T19:51:00.000

But there is something incomprehensible with preceding dates:

- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(0,0,1,2,29,50))` — 1900-01-01T01:59:50.000
- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(0,0,1))` — 1899-12-31T23:30:00.000
- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(-50,0,1))` — 1849-12-31T23:30:20.000
- `new LocalDateTime(new Date(-116,6,4))` — 1784-07-03T23:30:20.000

Who knows, what is this, and how to prevent this problem?

Comment: FWIW, those `Date()` constructors [are deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Have you tried the same examples using `Date`s created with [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)?

Comment: This constructor is used only for simplification. There is the same thing with other `Date`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which timezone are you using? It looks like you're dealing with a [clock discontinuity](http://timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=37&year=1893), possibly around 2 AM on January 1st, 1900. That means a certain amount of time was skipped by the local clock and officially *doesn't exist*. It could also be a change in DST. The consistent difference in your last 3 lines looks strange though - perhaps Java's Calendar and Joda Time use a different version of the timezone database and the change is missing in one of them.

You can check your timezone for changes at the linked-to site.